How can I get google analytics to track a Vendor Name (using page_post_Author variable in gtag) and show the vendor name?
Using google tag I got the custom data-layer variable setup. the COUNT is showing in Google Analytics as an event but I want the count to be sorted based on the VALUE of that variable.
i,e,
A visitor comes to the site and visits page_post_author = "RELAM".
I want to know how many visitors visited a page where the variable = "RELAM".
Not just the event count..
Can someone help?
google tag variable from data layer shows. however need a way to sort based on the value then count based on that value.
{
  event: "gtm.load",
  gtm: {
    uniqueEventId: 19,
    allowlist: undefined,
    blocklist: undefined,
    whitelist: undefined,
    blacklist: undefined,
    start: 1723216645903,
    priorityId: undefined
  },
  tagTypeBlacklist: undefined,
  developer_id: {dOGY3NW: true},
  pageTitle: "Fecon Mulching Head - RailRoad Trader",
  pagePostType: "product",
  pagePostType2: "single-product",
  pagePostAuthorID: 53,
  pagePostAuthor: "MacAllister Machinery", <<--- Here is the info that shows in variable: VENDORNAME.
  postCountOnPage: 1,
  postCountTotal: 1,
  productRatingCounts: [],
  productAverageRating: 0,
  productReviewCount: 0,

